# PHP make the whole container as link (not only the button)

Tags: php, wordpress

im a total php illiterate so i wanted to make a change in the php file of my wordpress website. i have some cards which represent my services but the clickable link is only in the "read more..." phrase but i want to make the whole card be as a link.
below is the php code i think is associated with that:

```
<?php elseif( $style == 'style_5' ) : ?>
    <h3><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h3>
<?php else : ?>
    <h4 class="no_stripe"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo wpb_js_remove_wpautop( $content, true ); ?>
<?php
    if ( $link['url'] ) {
        if ( ! $link['title'] ) {
            $link['title'] = esc_html__( 'Read More', 'consulting' );
        }
        if ( ! $link['target'] ) {
            $link['target'] = '_self';
        }
        if( $icon ){
            $link['title'] = '<span>' . esc_html( $link['title'] ) . '</span>' . '<i class=" ' . esc_attr( $icon ) . ' stm_icon"></i>';
        }
        echo ' <a class="read_more" target="' . esc_attr( $link['target'] ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link['url'] ) . '">' . $link['title'] . '</a>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php if( $style == 'style_3' ): ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html code, try to put the whole card inside of an 'a tag', this should make the whole card a link, and in the 'a tag' put your desired link in the href="". This should work!

Comment: thanks for the comment. i know how to do it in html but theres no html in wordpress unfortunately. :/

Comment: Hey try the same thing in php. I believe it should work just as well. Let me know if it does!

Comment: i explained in the question that im an php illiterate and i dont know how to do it in php :) thats why i posted this question here. someone to help me achieve it in php. i have the idea what i need to do i just dont understand the php syntax and i know that a single wrong character might break my site

Comment: If you know what an a tag is in html the use that a tag and put all of the stuff you want as a link inside of it. You said you are familiar with html.

Comment: ok, can you please take the php code i posted above and put everything properly in an a tag and send it back. thanks

Comment: `but theres no html in wordpress unfortunately` that statement does not seem accurate

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the link (from your code):

```
echo ' <a class="read_more" target="' . esc_attr( $link['target'] ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link['url'] ) . '">' . $link['title'] . '</a>';
```

So, I would simply try to wrap that around the container of your "card" by splitting it up into...

```
echo ' <a class="read_more" target="' . esc_attr( $link['target'] ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link['url'] ) . '">' . $link['title'];
```

...and:

```
echo '</a>';
```

The code of the container has to go between those two parts. Most likely that would be directly under the first line of the code you posted for the first part until the original position of the closing `a` tag. And since there is (non-php) HTML code in that section, that first line should be wrapped by php tags, like:

```
<?php echo ' <a target="' . esc_attr( $link['target'] ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link['url'] ) . '">' . $link['title']; ?>
```

Probably the "read more" class whould be avoided in the link now.

So the complete code would be

```html
<?php elseif( $style == 'style_5' ) : ?> 
    <?php echo ' <a target="' . esc_attr( $link['target'] ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link['url'] ) . '">' . $link['title']'; ?>
                <h3><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h3>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h4 class="no_stripe"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h4>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php echo wpb_js_remove_wpautop( $content, true ); ?>
    <?php
    if ( $link['url'] ) {
        if ( ! $link['title'] ) {
            $link['title'] = esc_html__( 'Read More', 'consulting' );
        }
        if ( ! $link['target'] ) {
            $link['target'] = '_self';
        }
        if( $icon ){
            $link['title'] = '<span>' . esc_html( $link['title'] ) . '</span>' . '<i class=" ' . esc_attr( $icon ) . ' stm_icon"></i>';
        }
         echo '</a>'; } ?>
<?php if( $style == 'style_3' ): ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

All this is based on the code you provided, there might be other stuff to consider, but you can try this.